# UPS supply cuts power at POST if connected to server via USB

Tags: power-supply, ups

I am using an EATON 3S 550 on a Server that uses 60W when idle It is an Intel Celeron G3220 on a Intel DH87RL. Due to the six harddrives the power used at boot is higher, but certainly below 550W, which is the VA rating of the EATON and also below 330W which is the Power rating of the Eaton. The PSU of the Server is rated 300W. Once, I had measured the Power (it was a while ago, but no change in Hardware since) the peak was 150W)
Eveything works fine, until I reboot the Server with the USB-Cable connected to the 3S.

In that case, it seems like the power supply is cut for a split second just after POST and the server does a cold boot. This happens again and again.

If I **disconnect** the USB connection between Server and 3S, everything works normally.

So, I conclude, that for some reason the USB connection between Server and UPS causes the power to be switched off for a short moment. [Edit: In fact, I am not sure the power is switched of: a Lamp connected to the UPS did not show any sign of power-cut, but of course it has some latency...] What could be the reason for this and more importandly: how can I fix or at least further isolate the problem? Due to the nature of the Problem, I fear that the only option to fix it would be some BIOS settings.

Regards,
Hendrik

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you might get different behavior trying the USB2 and USB3 ports.

Comment: https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/backup-power-ups-surge-it-power-distribution/backup-power-ups/eaton-3s-ups/eaton-3s-users-guide.pdf  Note the EcoFunction controls.

Comment: Does any USB port cause this behavior?  If you plug in any USB device do they cause this behavior?  Have you used an appropriate tool to determine your actual power usage?  I assume since you mentioned 550 W the server has a 550 W PSU.  However, it’s clear, you are absolutely not sure the PSU is enough for the actual power usage of the server.  If you unplug one of the HDD does the behavior happen?  Edit your question and please provide the necessary information to answer your question

Comment: @ChristopherHostage: Thanks. I did not activate the EcoFunctions though. Also, this would not explain different behaviour with USB plugged vs. not.

Comment: @Ramhound: I have added the information. I don't know how you conclude that "it's clear that I am absolutely not sure the PSU is enough for the power". How do you conclude that? Even more: if it was an overload-problem: Why would the behaviour be influenced by the USB of the UPS being connected to the Server or not?

Comment: @henfri can you post your solution as an answer rather than including it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue. Thanks for your inputs. 
Key was to use a different USB Port for the connection of the UPS to the server.
Then, I still had the problem, that the BIOS stopped the boot process, having noticed several unsuccessful boot attempts. This was a bit surprising, as the last attempts were all successful. Deactivating this watchdog solved this last issue then.